# How to fix err InvalidPipeArgument for date?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I tried to display date in specific format by pipe date then I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "25/01/2019" into a date' for pipe 'e'
    at Xe (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
    at e.transform (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
    at main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1
    at main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1
    at es (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
    at Cs (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
    at Object.updateRenderer (2.afd83a5d88a3f927f011.js:1)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
    at $a (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
    at us (main.fc4242d58c261cf678ad.js:1)
```

I received date info from API with `string` "25/01/2019" then I display on html like this:

```html
{{ item.date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}
```

I don't know I did some mistakes or not. But, What I want to do is display date in another format and date input is string type.

Can I do it? if yes what is the way in this case? Thanks a lot.

#### note: this error is not happen on localhost. at my localhost it is still working well. I met this when I deploy my web app to real environment.

Comment: [Have you kept something similar in your component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwoall?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Please try follwing ``{{ item.date | async | date:'dd MMM yyyy' }}`` , using ``async`` pipe is needed as long as you grab info from an API

Comment: thank you for your support. I think the problem is it is not a ISO string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) says

> The date expression: a Date object, a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch), or an ISO string

25/01/2019 is not an ISO string, 2019-01-25 is. NB : there are other date pipes outside the angular common package or you can make your on.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @David Palita's answer,

First you should convert from `String` to `Date`, then your can use `DatePipe` as you mentioned,

```
item.date = parseDate(item.date, 'dd/mm/YYYY');
```

If you reproduce your issue on stackblitz, we can make better directions for your case.

I also recommend you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) SO question.